# want to checkin a whole repository from local machine to svn

Tags: svn

We have multiple repositories in svn and one repository jst crashed and we don't have backups!
But I hav a 2 days old checked out copy of the same crashed repo.

Is there anyway I can create a new repo in the SVN server With the 2 days old checkout copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would seem to be creating a new repository and then importing the checked-out copy. Any reason why you can't do this?

Comment: As I'm new to SVN, I dont know much. But will I have the history if import? Thanks in advance